# Front panel microphone not always detected in Kubuntu

Tags: sound, kubuntu, alsa, microphone

I recently made the switch to Linux. However I have some issues with my headphone mic. My headphones have two jacks, one for the speakers and another for the microphone. I plug both  in the front panel ports. While the headphones' speakers are detected just fine, the mic is only detected if I replug the cable.

I have Kubuntu 21.10 with the latest updates installed and I am using PipeWire (from the PPA).

Do you have any ideas on what should I do? Feel free to ask for any config file or log. Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, May be caused by a physical problem: the 2.5 mm microphone or headphone jacks are many kinds, TS (mono) TTS (stereo) TRRS (stereo+mic). Normally microphone plug is TS or TRS but some ill-mannered plug has a TRRS or the jack is TRRS. Either way, the terminals don't fit well or jump into another. Check this before edit something inside the OS.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention it worked fine (and still does) on Windows. And the plug fits nicely and very tight after all.